# Load local files on startup of web app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, progressive-web-apps

I create a new progressive web app using React + Redux. The web app should show the local images of the device (smartphone) in a grid view. (similar to the native gallery app).

I would like to create a new Javascript function for getting the images from the smartphone as JSON. This is my action, which shall be run:

```js
export const getImages = () => {
return {
    type: 'GET_IMAGES',
    images: loadImages()
}
};

function loadImages() {
//Retrieve all the images from local storage

}
```

I already looked for possible solutions and found fileAPI. But I don't know, if it is possible to use it for this use case or if there could be a better solution because of the PWA service workers.

Comment: Which fileAPI do you mean? Provide reference please.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/file-upload/

Better described here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a mobile app, you should have a look at [React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/). This is React for mobile. Then you can use [Expo.io](https://expo.io/) and their [ImagePicker](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v17.0.0/sdk/imagepicker.html) function.

> **Returns**
>
> If the user cancelled the image picking, returns { cancelled: true }.
>
> Otherwise, returns { cancelled: false, uri, width, height } where uri is a URI to the local image file (useable in a react-native Image tag) and width, height specify the dimensions of the image.

Comment: Yes. But unfortunately, this is a project for my school. And I wanted to create a progressive web app. A app with React native is not a PWA